For Loop with and print function
having trouble with a for loop. I effectively have a set of 5 cells then need to go through a loop, which will affect calculations on a different page. Those calculations will give me a range of data points that I then want to copy to a new page and then repeat the process.
The output should be a range of cells from the calculation tab, that I would like pasted into the Output_tab.
Example code is below.
Sub Loop_seek
    
    Dim i as Integer Dim Output_tab as Worksheet
    
    For i = 1 to 6
        
        Range ("Selection_C").Value = Cells(i + 10, B).Value
        
        'this is value that changes selections on the next page for calculations
        
        Changeamount.Value = Cells (i +10, C)
        
        'is the value that will be changed to goal seek to value
        
        Range("TestAmount").GoalSeek:=0, ChangingCell:= Changeamount
        
        'productvalue is a named range of cells on the calculation tap I want to copy to a new tab and print
        
        Range("productvalue").copy Destination=Output_tab (I+2, D)
        
        'pasting in defined tab starting in column d with the applicable row
        
    Next i
    
End Sub


What do you expect to happen and what does actually happen?

Since you are dealing with multiple sheets, it's probably a good idea to qualify what sheet a given range is on. For example Cells(i + 10, B).Value Should be something like Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 10, B).Value (This may be a side note or it may solve the problem)

Best guess
Option Explicit

Sub Loop_seek()
    
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsInput = ActiveSheet ' or better .Sheets("Input_tab")
        Set wsOutput = .Sheets("Output_tab")
    End With
    
    With wsInput
        For i = 1 To 6
            Range("Selection_C") = .Cells(i + 10, "B")
            
            'this is value that changes selections on the next page for calculations
            Range("ChangeAmount") = .Cells(i + 10, "C")
            
            'is the value that will be changed to goal seek to value
            Range("TestAmount").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("ChangeAmount")
            
            'productvalue is a named range of cells on the calculation tap
            'I want to copy to a new tab and print
            
            Range("productvalue").Copy wsOutput.Cells(i + 2, "D")
            'pasting in defined tab starting in column d with the applicable row
            
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub

